# Simple way to "mix" respectively two lists in python?

Tags: python, file, list

I have the following issue:

I need to "mix" respectively two lists in python...

I have this:

```
names = open('contactos.txt')
numbers = open('numeros.txt')
names1 = []
numbers1= []
for line in numbers:
    numberdata = line.strip()
    numbers1.append(numberdata)
print numbers1

for line in names:  
    data = line.strip()
    names1.append(data)
print names1

names.close()
numbers.close()
```

This prints abot 300 numbers first, and the respective 300 names later, what I need to do is to make a new file (txt) that prints the names and the numbers in one line, separated by a comma (,), like this:

```
Name1,64673635
Name2,63513635
Name3,67867635
Name4,12312635
Name5,78679635
Name6,63457635
Name7,68568635
..... and so on...
```

I hope you can help me do this, I've tried with "for"s but I'm not sure on how to do it if I'm iterating two lists at once, thank you :)

Comment: Does it have to be python? or does a bash solution also work for what you need it for?

Comment: One a side note, when accessing files, it's a good idea to use context managers: `with open(filename) as file: \ # process file` where the '\' represents the line break. This construct ensures that your files are always closed regardless of any irregular behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize `zip`:

```
for num, name in zip(numbers, names):
    print('{0}, {1}'.format(num, name))
```

Comment: Or alternatively use `itertools.izip` so you don't read the entire file at once (unless you're using Python 3, in which case what you've written is fine)

Comment: Your solution is correct, except the arguments given should be "numbers1" and "names1" because those are the lists names, I fixed it and now it works, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`zip` will combine the two lists together, letting you write them to a file:

```
In [1]: l1 = ['one', 'two', 'three']

In [2]: l2 = [1, 2, 3]

In [3]: zip(l1, l2)
Out[3]: [('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3)]
```

However you can save yourself a bit of time. In your code, you are iterating over each file separately, creating a list from each. You could also iterate over both at the same time, creating your list in one sweep:

```
results = []
with open('contactos.txt') as c:
    with open('numeros.txt') as n:
       for line in c:
          results.append([line.strip(), n.readline().strip()])


print results
```

This uses a `with` statement (context manager), that essentially handles the closing of files for you. This will iterate through `contactos`, reading a line from `numeros` and appending the pair to the list. You can even cut out the list step and write directly to your third file in the same loop:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    with open('contactos.txt', 'r') as c:
        with open('numeros.txt', 'r') as n:
            for line in c:
                output.write('{0}, {1}\n'.format(line.strip(), n.readline().strip()))
```

Answer (score 3):

A "pythonic" way to mix two lists in this way is the [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function!

```
names = open('contactos.txt')
numbers = open('numeros.txt')
names1 = []
numbers1= []
for line in numbers:
    numberdata = line.strip()
    numbers1.append(numberdata)

for line in names:  
    data = line.strip()
    names1.append(data)

names.close()
numbers.close()

for name, number in zip(names1, numbers1):
    print '%s, %s' % (name number)
```

There are other and better ways to print formatted text (e.g. Yuushi's answer). I also like to use the `with` statement and list comprehensions, e.g.

```
with open('contactos.txt') as f:
    names = [line.strip() for line in f]

with open('numeros.txt') as f:
    numbers = [line.strip() for line in f]

for name, number in zip(names, numbers):
    print '%s, %s' % (name, number)
```

Finally, I just want to comment on how you could do it without the zip function. I'm not sure what you want to do if there are a different number of numbers and names, but you can use a `for` loop like this for the last bit to access the values from both lists in a single for loop:

```
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    print '%s, %s' % (names[i], numbers[i])
```

This code in particular will throw an exception if there are more names than numbers, so you would probably want to add some code to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Everything at once:

```
import itertools

with open('contactos.txt') as names, open('numeros.txt') as numbers:
    for num, name in itertools.izip(numbers, names):
        print '%s, %s' % (num.strip(), name.strip())
```

This reads the two files in parallel, rather than reading each file completely into memory one at a time.